# Make the first <li> in a separate row, and rest <li> in two rows & columns

Tags: css

I have list that have two columns:

```
ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
  }
```

This will make all the

to be in two rows. I want the first

to be in a separate row at the top, and the rest in two columns below it like:

```
A
B C
D E
```

I have tried selectors such as;

```
 ul:first-child {
      display:inline-block;
  }
```

But it does not work. How to do it?

Comment: can you share the workable HTML code as well, for that you getting the above mentioned result.

Comment: It is always recommended to share a small snippet of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve with help of **display: flex** property & first list should be 100% width like **li:first-child { width: 100% }**.
I hope this snippet will help you.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  ul {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
  }
  ul li{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  ul li:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  ul li span{
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 4px 8px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span></li>
  <li><span>C</span></li>
  <li><span>D</span></li>
  <li><span>E</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly you want to choose the first child of the list item and not the first list. then you can change the `column-span` property for the first list item like so:

```css
ul {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}

li:first-child {
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

unfortunately, you can't arrange the columns in a horizontal way in this way.
if that's what you  need you should use flexbox as the other answer suggested.